# How to control two separate circuits with one switch?

Tags: led, switches, relay, circuit-design, dpdt

I have two separate circuits with different types of diodes. One circuit draws 3,5V and the other draws 9V. How can I wire this up so that one switch can turn both circuits on or off? As far as I understand I can do this with a relay. What kind of relay would I use?

This is **NOT** a duplicate of former question

[Controlling Two Circuits with One Switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215234/controlling-two-circuits-with-one-switch)

...as some of the people here seem to believe.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you downvote. Otherwise it's impossible to improve the quality of the questions. *Of course* I had looked at similar questions and googled the issue before I asked. And no, it's not answered before in the question "Controlling Two Circuits with One Switch".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dual-pole switch. DPDT or DPST.

That’s two separate switches that share mechanics.

The same naming convention also applies to relays.

Comment: I Googled this extensively (and saw several videos on YouTube) before I posted the question, and didn't get the feeling this would solve my issue. Keep in mind that the two circuits are completely different, have different voltages, different components and different resistance. By flipping a single switch, I'd like to turn both separate circuits *on*.

Comment: @Pedery there is absolutely no electrical connection between the poles of a DPxT devise. Be it a switch or a relay. As long as you don’t exceed the ratings the circuits will be functionally isolated from each other.

Comment: Thanks, then this is exactly what I need. I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer. I assume such a switch can also work in reverse, so that flipping one switch on means the other automatically goes off?

Comment: @Pedery for that you would need a DPDT. So you can connect each “throw” differently.

Comment: Thanks! As for my original question, my intention was to control the switching mechanism with a low voltage battery. I already have a switch in the system that could switch this initial circuit on/off (for physically practical reasons), and this in turn should make current flow in the two other circuits mentioned above. Are we still talking about a DPDT switch, or is a relay the most appropriate component?

Comment: @Pedery I don’t follow what you are asking. A switch you actuate physically with your hand. A relay is actuated by an electrical drive signal. Those are different functions.

Comment: Exactly! I have a huge physical existing switch that should be used to turn the two circuits on and off. This is for aesthetical reasons. It should provide a drive signal, i.e. from a battery, that should activate the two other circuits. So maybe there are some kinds of DPDT relays that can be connected to the two aforementioned circuits, with a drive signal from the huge trigger switch?

Comment: All you need is one DPDT relay with a coil that can be directly actuated with the voltage of your primary switch.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll buy something off Ebay and give it a try :)

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f78YRZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An example of using a DPST switch to control two circuits simultaneously while maintaining isolation.*

Answer (score 0):

If they have common ground, put switch on the ground side

Comment: "I have two separate circuits ..."

Comment: Then it's DPST as mentioned in other responses.